# cover a text input with a dialog

Tags: javascript, html

I'm trying to put a dialog with two options "yes and no" that covers a text input so the user have to choise one of the options before he can be able to type in. It should be transparent and only covers the text input only.

What's the trick that i can use in such case ?

Comment: no trick, you just use code, do you have any?

Comment: @JordanHendrix for now I don't have any idea how to do that. but i only know that it could be done with some javascript code. I looked around but nothing.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can set `input` `disabled` attribute to `true`, set `button` elements `css` `position` to `absolute` to cover `input`; at `click` of `button` elements, set `top` of `button` elements to position below `input` , adjust `opacity` of `button` elements; remove `disabled` attribute at `input`; set `button` `onclick` handler to `null`

```js
var buttons = document.querySelectorAll("button");
var input = document.querySelector("input");
var label = document.querySelector("label");
for (var i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++) {
  buttons[i].onclick = function(e) {
    label.innerHTML = e.target.innerHTML;
    input.removeAttribute("disabled");
    for (var j = 0; j < buttons.length; j ++) {
      buttons[j].className = "show";
      buttons[j].disabled = true;
      buttons[j].onclick = null;
    }
  }
}
```

```css
button {
  display:block;
  width: 75px;
  height:50px;
  appearance:button;
  opacity:.5;
  position:absolute;
}

button:nth-of-type(2) {
  left:82px;
}

input {
  width:145px;
}

.show {
  top:28px;
  opacity:.25;
}
```

```html
<button>Yes</button><button>No</button>
<input type="text" disabled /><label></label>
```

Answer (score 1):

To simplify add the 'disabled' attribute to the input first. This will prevent the user from typing in the input.

```
<input type="text" id="inputId" disabled"/>
```

Then create the dialog with two buttons yes and no. Attach a js function to the yes block that enables the text input and gets rid of the dialog box.

```
<button onclick="yesFunc()">Yes</button>
function yesFunc() {
    document.getElementById('inputId').removeAttr('disabled');
    document.getElementByI('dialogId').css('display','none');
}
```

Then from there its all styling